# How to prevent submit buttons not to show the url in the address bar?

Tags: url, firefox, submit-button

Folks,
I just noticed something interesting developing my first ASP.Net Mvc application and Its when you mouse over on a submit button in Mozilla the full Url is shown in the status bar! Is it a normal behavior?! how can i prevent that?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to prevent that?!

Comment: Just a wish! ain't it possible? @Quentin

Comment: Hiding something that has little purpose beyond helping people avoid being phished seems rather blackhat.

Comment: Frankly spoken ain't it a door opened to the hackers?! I think so but not so sure about it  I am too far away from that just started coding :P @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="text">
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Send" > -->
            <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="onClick(this)">
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onClick (e)
            {
                document.forms["myForm"].submit();

            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```